# How do i remove empty parameter using beanshell preprocessor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to read a csv file that contains more that 500+ rows and each row will serve as request to API. Now my problem is that some of the parameters have empty string and i would like to set up a condition in case if parameter returns empty string then remove that parameter from request body upfront before hitting the API

Below is my json

```
{
  "body": {
    "Id1": "${Id1}",
    "addressId": "${addressId}",
    "languageCode": "${languageCode}",
    "tempId": "${tempId}"
}
```

Now after reading csv i get following values in my request body

```
{
  "body": {
    "Id1": "1",
    "addressId": "1233",
    "languageCode": "E",
    "tempId": ""
}
```

As you can see tempId has empty string. Now using bean-shell preprocessor i am trying to remove this but no luck

```
Object requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();

if (requestBody.get("tempId").equals("")){
    sampler.getArguments.removeArgument("tempId");
}
```

when i look into result tree i don't see tempId being deleted from the request. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using Beanshell for deprecation and bad performance.

Use [groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) instead with this code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def newRequest = evaluate(request.inspect())
request.body.each { entry ->
    if (entry.getValue().equals('')) {
        newRequest.body.remove(entry.getKey())
    }
}
def arguments = new Arguments();
sampler.setArguments(arguments);
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(newRequest), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

See:

- [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace in body `"tempId": "${tempId}"` with `${tempIdEval}` and calculate value in [JSR223 script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor)

```
String tempIdEval = vars.get("tempId");
vars.put("tempIdEval", (port == null ? "" : "\"tempId\": \"" + tempIdEval + "\""));
```

> Migration to JSR223 PreProcessor+Groovy is highly recommended for performance, support of new Java features and limited maintenance of the BeanShell library.

Comment: instead of vars.put what if i do vars.remove("tempId") ? Does that work ?

Comment: @JonAbraham but you have a `tempIdEval` placeholder in request, so don't do it

Comment: what if i don't use tempIdEval placeholder and instead use "tempId":"${tempId}" in my requestbody as posted above in original question. In that case would it be possible to do vars.remove("tempId") ? I intend to completely remove empty key/value instead of marking it as null

Comment: @JonAbraham No becacue you will send irrelevant text `"tempId":"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using beanshell preprocessor, we can use like

```
   if (vars.get("tempId")!="")
       vars.put("variablename","not null");

   else 
       vars.put("variablename","is null");
```

and use the "variablename" instead. You can manipulate the string as well as below.

```
if (${tempId}=="")
{ vars.put("json","
   {
   "body": {
    "Id1": "${Id1}",
    "addressId": "${addressId}",
    "languageCode": "${languageCode}""
   }
}
else
{ vars.put("json","
   {
   "body": {
    "Id1": "${Id1}",
    "addressId": "${addressId}",
    "languageCode": "${languageCode}",
    "tempId": "${tempId}"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

The relevant Groovy code for [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) which removes JSON attributes with empty values would be something like:

```
def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def newRequest = evaluate(request.inspect())
request.body.each { entry ->
    if (entry.getValue().equals('')) {
        newRequest.body.remove(entry.getKey())
    }
}
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(newRequest).toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Great solution this worked perfectly for me. Also thank you for reminding me that from Jmeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223. When i tried to run test with number of threads - 5, ramp up period in seconds -1, loop count - 1 then i am able to see the result. But when i try no. of threads - 6, ramp up time - 120, loop count -forever then i am seeing in result tree as POST data being empty. Any idea on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getValue() on null object